# Terminal 'ls' command not showing files when newly generated

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, bash

I generate files to the public folder using `ng-cli` from my terminal

Using this command `ng build`

Another terminal is open to the public folder while files are generated ...  I run `ls` but **it's not working** I must go back then re-enter the folder to show the files and folders generated !!!

```
Osamas-MacBook-Pro:public osama$ ls
Osamas-MacBook-Pro:public osama$ ls
Osamas-MacBook-Pro:public osama$ cd ..
Osamas-MacBook-Pro:dawaeymean osama$ cd public
Osamas-MacBook-Pro:public osama$ ls
favicon.ico     main.bundle.js      styles.bundle.js
index.html      main.bundle.js.map  styles.bundle.js.map
inline.bundle.js    polyfills.bundle.js vendor.bundle.js
inline.bundle.js.map    polyfills.bundle.js.map vendor.bundle.js.map
```

***why `ls` is not just reflected in real time changes?***

Comment: How much time is occurring between each command?

Comment: About ~20 seconds

Comment: try typing `source ~/.bashrc` It should rest your bash settings.

Comment: Is this folder mounted from a server, or something like that?

Comment: @GordonDavisson it's generated with `webpack` on local drive